# MongoDB Unable to push to array with findOneAndUpdate()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js

Been working on a project recently where users subscribe to a class... however I am having trouble with pushing the class to the array... here is my code

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    secret: String,
    classes: [String]
});
const userModel = mongoose.model("Class", userSchema)

app.post("/subscribe", function (req, res) {
    const newClass = req.body.subClass;
    const id = req.user.id
    const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
    userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: new ObjectId(id) },
        { $addToSet: { letters: [newClass] } },
        { upsert: false }
    );
});
```

I skipped through the program for useful info so please comment if more code is needed... looking to finally finish this up!

Comment: does that findOneAndUpdate return anything?

Comment: `const userModel = mongoose.model("Class", userSchema)` why did you specify *Class* as userModel ? Also to which field are pushing ? Is that `classes` or `letters` ? If you're pushing to `letters` then you need to have that field mentioned in `userSchema` otherwise mongoose doesn't let query to add that field to DB !!

Comment: I just realized I never changed it to classes from when I was working on another project... will update tomorrow if that fixes it

Comment: app.post("/subscribe", function (req, res) {
 ```const newClass = req.body.subClass;
    const id = req.user.id
    const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: new ObjectId(id) },
        { $push: { classes: newClass } },
        { upsert: false, new: true }
    );
    res.redirect("/dashboard")
});``` this is still not working for some reason... I changed to my other user model : ```const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema)```